# How to initialize 'BehaviorSubject' in test Component?

Tags: unit-testing, behaviorsubject

In TS File,Datasource is initialised in a following way,
  public dataSource: Observable = new BehaviorSubject([]);

How to Initialize in SPEC file

Answer (score 0):

In the .spec file, you will need to seed your datasource with an initial state, as per test practices. In javascript:

```
const datasource = new BehaviorSubject("a");
```

**Additional**: then run function to test that acts on `datasource`, i.e.:

```
setToB() // i.e: datasource.next("b")
datasource.subscribe(val => val.shouldEqual("b"))
```